# Pre-Sales: multiple content moderators and security

Tags: php, general-knowledge

I'm trying to check if Expression engine is the correct product for a new project. I received the request from a customer to build a portal for a sporting association. This company organizes activities for a lot of different sports. Each of these sports have their dedicated content page(s) (with submenu). Each of these sports also has dedicated content editor(s) meaning which don't have access to the other sports. Each sports section should also have a dedicated agenda.

The main site will also have content moderators and a dedicated agenda for overall activities.

Could you advice me if Expression Engine is the correct product. Are their other alternatives? I need to be able to manage the security vary granular, common components in templates should not be modified by lower level moderators, etc...

Thanks, Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like ExpressionEngine could meet your needs. One straightforward approach would be to create a separate channel and member type for each sport. You would then assign rights to edit only that channel to each associated member type. These content editors would not have access to any of the underlying templates or data. Users with SuperAdmin (or similar) credentials could act as content moderators. Note, you can have each channel share the same channel fields so can avoid some of the redundancy between related channels.

You can read more about member groups and setting control panel permissions here: 
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/members/member_groups_edit.html